# Should I use Recurring Profiles (Beta) for my recurly recurring payments module?

Tags: magento

This probably seems like a stupid question off hand, and maybe it is actually, but there are a few specific reasons I'm leaning away from using them.  The paypal recurring profiles implementation seems like it doesn't work very well for a couple reasons:

1. There are a number of bugs in the process, including that new customers aren't created for first time checkouts using it.
2. Orders don't seem to be created for Recurring Profiles - maybe I have something misconfigured...?
3. Recurring Profiles have a Related Orders association, which is empty for my tests.
4. Apparently, Transactions are supposed to be used for recurring profiles (I read that on another thread recently), however I don't see those being populated either, needless to say.

What I'm leaning towards is the following:

1. Products can be associated to Subscription Plans within Recurly
2. During checkout, if a product with an association to a Subscription Plan is in the cart, the Recurly payment method will be available.
3. Upon purchase, an account and subscription will be created for the Magento user account.
4. In addition to the Order that is created, I will create a Transaction and associate it to the Order.
5. On the successful_payment_notification, I will insert a fresh Transaction against the original Order.
6. In the My Account section for the end user, I will extend the order detail template with a list of transactions.
7. Having a config option to suppress the Recurring Profiles section from My Account to avoid confusion on the part of the end users.

I'm sure someone much smarter than me has thought through this already, look forward to any insight you may be able to offer!  Thanks!

UPDATE: My original question was kind of broken into two parts: one being why aren't my recurring profiles working even with PayPal, and the other being - does it make sense to use Recurring Profiles for my subscriptions feature.  I didn't really get any answer for the latter, so I accepted the answer that was given to assist with the former issue.

I have since posted a new question related specifically to the question of whether or not to use Recurring Profiles: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/should-i-use-recurring-profiles-for-subscriptions-feature

Comment: I highly encourage anyone interested on this feature to take a look to my answer there too. :) https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318495/555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem and just found this:
[Working with Recurring Profiles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles)
where written that:

> The Related Orders tab lists the orders which have been created according to the payment system notifications referenced by this recurring profile.
>
> **Important**
>
> To have information updated on the Recurring Profile View page, Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) must be set up in merchant account of the PayPal payment system.

I guess this is the solution to the problem

Comment: Hey thanks Aram.  But there's also the issue of new customers not being created for first time checkouts?  Have you had any luck using this module?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1751/ this might be solution for your problem "System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Allow Guest Checkout -> No". I've tried and it created user and loged in after successful checkout.